# "This file is not ready to be fetched"- exception occurs when trying to load image from Parse table

Tags: parse-platform

When I'm trying to load image using `-[PFImageView loadInBackground:]` I'm getting exception some time like

`Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'This file is not ready to be fetched.'`. But not often. It make the app crash.

Im searching for the reason and solution for a long but didn't got exact solution.

Any suggestion to solve this please ?

Comment: Can you provide the code where you download the PFObject which the image is associated with. Can you also provide more code of how you are loading the image. Providing only the function name is not very helpful.

Comment: i actually using a NSOperationQueue to load the image file with maxConcurrentOperationCount as 2 and it should be like this in the NSOperation [self.imageView loadInBackground:^(UIImage *image, NSError *error) { if (self.callback) { self.callback(image, error); } }];

Comment: And the code to fetch PFObject is more like the basic PFQuery